Specify default user on the MacOS login screen?
Currently, it seems to default alphabetically, so 'Adam' would be default rather than 'Eve.', but I prefer the 'Eve' as the default user.   Currently, you have to press Escape, cancelling out of 'Adam' (for example), click focus on 'Eve' and then enter password.
I would have hoped MacOS would offer an elegant solution, but I have not yet found it.
I hope to power on or reboot, then the login screen defaults to 'Eve,' and all I need to do is enter the password rather than select an account that isn’t Alphabetically sorted first in the list.
Is there a method for specifying the default user on the MacOS login screen?

On modern macOS hardware, you’re not running the OS at the boot log in screen. Firmware knows what accounts are available to unlock the boot volume and after you authenticate with a correct password for a user allowed to boot, then the OS starts after the storage encryption is unlocked. Would it work to remove the other account so it can’t unlock or boot? Once the OS is loaded, you can still switch users, just you’ll be forced to log in to the default account.
